# Is there any standard approach for generating tables, web-views and request -handlers by entity description?

Tags: java, database-design, datatemplate

My problem is  that I know description of some process and want to search some standard technology implementing such approach, but don't know the correct name. In short, I need "objects-templating" engine. In details, I need to automate the following process:

1. Admin/operator declares object description: fields, types, such as a
   programmer declares a class, but not in the code, but in the web
   interface.
2. Created in web-interface entity **forces automatic change of the DB structure** - a table is created or existing table updated.
3. Another person (user) presses presses add button and see **automatically generated view-form** for creating or updating an entity.

Sum up- I'm looking for a technology which allows to create new objects with UI,automatically change DB structure, create view-forms for rendering/saving entity. If possible, **form-action handler must also be created automatically**, ie it generates a servlet / request mapping in controller, which inserts to DB/loads from DB.

I'm interested in Java technologies/frameworks as my question is asked in Java Web-App context.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems [Spring Roo](http://docs.spring.io/spring-roo/) is what I need.